# How do I animate a Label background image?

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

#### My Problem

I have a simple design with two labels on the screen, one under the other. Each Label has 3 circles which I need to animate diagonally. When the circle(s) reach the border of its Label, it comes out at the top and loops. ( please see horrible diagram )

[image: Diagram of desired animation]

#### My Failed Attempts

Well, I have tried everything I can think of. I used this approach:

**XML**

```
<Label id="Label1" class="ticket-font watermark" height="150" textAlignment="center" textWrap="true" text=" 1 Unlimited" backgroundColor="#f25092" tap = "onTap"/>
   <Label id="Label2" class="ticket-font2 watermark2" height="150" textAlignment="center" textWrap="true" text="Monthly Pass" backgroundColor="#ed166e" tap = "onTap"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.an1 {
    animation-name: backAnimate;
    animation-duration: 1000;
}
@keyframes backAnimate{
    from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    to { transform: translate(150, 320); }
}

.watermark {

    background-image: url("~/images/water.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background-position: left top;


}
```

the above is not working code, it shows how I tried to solve my problem. It failed miserable.

So basically, I would render the Labels, add the watermarks (circles) as background image for the Label, and then when its loaded fully, or some other event, I would add the animation class.

But it doesn't work. Not even close results.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you for looking.

John

Comment: I don't see `an1` class being applied anywhere, can you share a Playground sample?

Comment: Sample coming tonight. Sorry for delay, darned health problems, I am on it, though. Thanks.

Comment: Here is my non working Playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=hsQCxe&v=4

Comment: You can not animate background image, so you will have to use `Image` for loading circle image and apply transform animation on it. Also mention the unit for `animation-duration` in CSS, like `1s` (1 second) / `4s` (4 seconds). More info / examples can be found at [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation-css).

Comment: As always, @Manoj , your thoroughness is much appreciated. I will attempt your suggestion and update here. For now, I will accept your answer. Thanks!